# UPDATE column with SUM from two other columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax, sum

I have a sum question. I'm trying to update a column with a SUM from two other columns and I'm getting an error "An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.". I tried using a sub query but I get the same error. Can someone please set me straight on what I need to get this to work I'm about to pull out my hair!! (not really ;))

```
    UPDATE t SET Admin4=
         CASE WHEN cb.ProductID=vp.ProductID THEN CAST(SUM(vp.Split) - 
 SUM(rl.Split)
AS money) ELSE '' END
FROM #tmp t
INNER JOIN SCH.dbo.tblProducts vp ON t.ProductID=vp.ProductID
INNER JOIN SCH.dbo.tblProductsChargeBack cb ON vp.productID=cb.productID
INNER JOIN SCH.dbo.tblLookUp rl ON vp.LookupID=rl.LookUpID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This .It may help you out

```
  ;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT cb.ProductID,CASE WHEN cb.ProductID=vp.ProductID THEN CAST(SUM(vp.Split) - SUM(rl.Split) AS money) ELSE '' END  AS Admin4
FROM #tmp t
INNER JOIN SCH.dbo.tblProducts vp ON t.ProductID=vp.ProductID
INNER JOIN SCH.dbo.tblProductsChargeBack cb ON vp.productID=cb.productID
INNER JOIN SCH.dbo.tblLookUp rl ON vp.LookupID=rl.LookUpID
GROUP BY  cb.ProductID
)

UPDATE T SET T.Admin4=c.Admin4
from #tmp t
 INNER JOIN cte c on  t.ProductID=c.ProductID
```

**Note:** You are trying to to Cast to datatype `Money` . `Money and SmallMoney` data types will works from `SQL Server (starting with 2008)`. For your reference follow [Money and Small Money](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/money-and-smallmoney-transact-sql)

Comment: Hi Mahesh. I tried that and still get "An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement." Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: I think I need to add a sub query in order to get this to work but not totally sure..

Comment: Probably ..let me try this .Meanwhile refer this link for any solution https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162745/use-sum-in-update-statement

Comment: Thanks for your assistance Mahesh but I think we got it!

Comment: Welcome Pete ..I've updated the answer in different way .make a try once .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
UPDATE t SET Admin4=
                (SELECT CAST(SUM(vp.Split) - SUM(rl.Split) AS money) FROM 
        SCH.dbo.tblProducts vp 
        INNER JOIN SCH.dbo.tblProductsChargeBack cb ON vp.productID=cb.productID
        INNER JOIN SCH.dbo.tblLookUp rl ON vp.LookupID=rl.LookUpID; 
        WHERE t.ProductID=vp.ProductID )
FROM #tmp t
```

Comment: Yes that worked Serkan! A big THANK YOU for your assistance!

Comment: You're welcome Pete! ( https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers )

Answer (score 0):

Just a cleaned up version of your update

```
UPDATE t 
SET Admin4 = CASE WHEN cb.ProductID = vp.ProductID THEN CAST(SUM(vp.Split-rl.Split) AS money) 
                  ELSE '' 
             END
FROM #tmp t
INNER JOIN SCH.dbo.tblProducts vp 
        ON t.ProductID  = vp.ProductID
INNER JOIN SCH.dbo.tblProductsChargeBack cb 
        ON cb.productID = vp.productID
INNER JOIN SCH.dbo.tblLookUp rl 
        ON rl.LookUpID  = vp.LookupID;
```

You cannot use an aggregate (the sum) in an update.  Besides an aggregate requires a group by.

```
CASE WHEN cb.ProductID = vp.ProductID
```

Above makes no sense as that is a join condition and will always be true.

Try this

```
UPDATE t 
SET Admin4 = tt.ssum
FROM #tmp t 
JOIN (select vp.productID
           , CAST(SUM(vp.Split-rl.Split) AS money)  as ssum  
        FROM SCH.dbo.tblProducts vp             
        JOIN SCH.dbo.tblProductsChargeBack cb 
          ON cb.ProductID = vp.ProductID
        JOIN SCH.dbo.tblLookUp rl 
          ON rl.LookUpID  = vp.LookupID 
       GROUP BY vp.productID)
     ) tt 
  ON t.productID = tt.productID
```

Don't see the purpose to `JOIN SCH.dbo.tblProductsChargeBack cb` as cb is not used.